# ¿Cómo crear un único Servicio Web para múltiples gestores de bases de datos?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, oracle, webservice, mariadb

¡Hola, buenas tardes!

Estoy pensando crear un único **Servicio Web** para poder implementar todas las funcionalidades del negocio para dos empresas del mismo rubro, todos los procesos de negocios son idénticos. De estas empresas, una de ellas contará con un gestor de base de datos **SQL Server** y un servidor **Windows**; mientras que la otra empresa usará (**MySQL** o **MariaDB**) y un servidor **Linux**. Después de finalizado el servicio web, empezaré a crear aplicaciones web y móviles para estas empresas, pero quiero tener un solo servicio web para darle mantenimiento.

Necesito ayuda para pensar en que tecnologías serían las más adecuadas para desarrollar un único servicio web, para estas empresas. He trabajado como programador, tengo conocimientos en **Java** (JSF), **C#** (Web Forms, MVC, Net Core), **JavaScript** (JQuery, Vue), **PHP** (Laravel), **SQL Server**, **MySQL**, **CSS** y **HTML**.

**No tengo experiencia como arquitecto de software.** ¿Algunas sugerencias que me puedan dar para investigar sobre tecnologías a usar?

Estaré agradecido por su colaboración.

**Atte., Shoy777**

Comment: Por favor lee [ask], las preguntas basadas en opiniones terminan cerrada, acumula 20 de rep. Y podrás entrar al [chat] donde tu duda será mejor recibida

Comment: Te sugiero que investigues acerca de ORMs